# microbit is unable to flash board with a Windows ARM64 laptop

Tags: webusb, bbc-microbit, windows-arm64

When using a Windows 11 ARM64 laptop, I encounter difficulties flashing my microbit program to the board. Could you please advise if there are any plans to support the Windows ARM64 platform in microbit or WebUSB?

1. Coding completed a microbit program.
2. Connect the board using a USB cable.
3. Attempted to flash the board, but encountered issues and was unable to complete the flashing process.

Comment: We verified it on a surface arm64 dev kit (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/dev-kit/) and it doesn't have the issue flashing the microbit using https://makecode.microbit.org/. Is this issue only to that specific laptop or chipset of the laptop?